# Copying range from one worksheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy everything from column A in sheet1 to sheet2. The issue is that it won't be a static range, i.e the numbers of rows in column A isn't constant. Below is what I'm using that works for 100 rows, how would I change it to work for x rows? Thanks very much in advance.

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A102").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A5:A105").Value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
x = 100
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Resize(x).Value = _
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A5").Resize(x).Value
```

if you want to use last used row instead `x`, look into this answer: [How to determine last used row/column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba/11169920#11169920)

Comment: thanks! the last used row was exactly what i needed!